# Complex compound SQL queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm fairly rusty at SQL as its been a long time since I've used it and I've rarely needed to do complex queries even when I have.

I have a database with data columns as follows:

```
Key, Instance, User ID, Day, Size
```

**Key** - This is the primary key.
**Instance** - This is a descriptor of the specific instance (this will be unique).
**User ID** - This will refer to 1 of a number of users where the number will be less than the number of entries in this table.
**Day** - This is the day the specific user created this instance.  It will be one of either Day 1 or Day 2.
**Size**- This is the size of the data stored.

Now not all users will have created instances on 2 days (though they may have created multiple instances on either day).

I'm after a query that will Select the Instance with the largest size on Day 1 where that user ID also created an Instance on Day 2.

I'm completely lost as to where to start on this one.

I wrote some C# code that filtered the results returned from a far simpler SQL query, however it is way too slow to give me the kind of results I would like.

Am I hoping for too much from SQL (ie is what I ask even possible)?  IF so can anyone give me an example of such a query with an explanation of what each step of the, presumably, compound query is doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Top 1 Key, Instance, UserId, Day, Size
From Table1 
Where UserId IN (Select UserId from Table1 where Day = 'Day 2') 
And Day = 'Day 1'
Order By Size asc
```

Comment: This answer doesn't look, at first glance, as perfect as athabaska's but still provides me with a far better understanding of compound queries than I had, so thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The answer is in fact to give you the right direction for your development ;)

Comment: I am not sure this one will work as you specified. See, "Where exists( Select UserId from Table1 where Day = 'Day 2')" just checks id there any record in table with Day2. So it has nothing to do with your condition of user having both days 1 and 2.

Comment: It probably should have been "Where UserId IN ( Select UserId from Table1 where Day = 'Day 2')" ?

Comment: I've gone with this method as I found it far easier to understand!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Top 1 t1.*
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 on t1.UserID = t2.UserID AND t2.Day = 2
WHERE t1.Day = 1   
ORDER BY Size DESC
```

As for explanation - your table is joined to itself so result will have rows for users that have both days activity. The result is sorted by size in descending order, and only first row is returned, which should have largest size.

Comment: This looks perfect ... I'm just gonna check out how it works with my actual DB (I used a stripped down example)

Comment: Thanks, but I did have trouble implementing this where Nadeem_MK's was far easier to get working so I accepted their answer.