# Complex SQL query excluding results from other SQL queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

This question is a continuation from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113944/complex-compound-sql-queries)

There is a slight change to the database structure however (as I over simplified slightly)

I have a database with data columns as follows:

```
Key, Instance, User ID, Day, Size, Instance Type
```

**Key** - This is the primary key.
**Instance** - This is a descriptor of the specific instance (this will be unique).
**User ID** - This will refer to 1 of a number of users where the number will be less than the number of entries in this table.
**Day** - This is the day the specific user created this instance. It will be one of either Day 1 or Day 2.
**Size** - This is the size of the data stored.
**Instance Type** - There are several instance types An instance, itself, will be one of these instance types.

Now in my previous question I was building a nested SQL query to find a distinct users who has instance on day 1 and day 2 and in this case with a specific instance type.

Now I have 2 sets of these queries.

What I would now like to do is a 3rd query and return the database where the **User ID** does not exist in either of the other queries.

So far I have set up a query but it is REALLY slow (Something to do with the <> comparator in the *On* statement) and I'm not even 100% sure it does exactly what I want.

This is my SQL statement so far:

```
Select  Max( Table.Key ) as Key, 
        Max( Table.Instance ) as Instance, 
        Table.[User ID], 
        Max( Table.Day ) as Day,
        Max( Table.Size ) as Size,
        Max( Table.[Instance Type] ) as [Instance Type]
from (((Table 
        inner join  (Select top 90  Max( Table.Key ) as Key, 
                                    Max( Table.Instance ) as Instance, 
                                    Table.[User ID], 
                                    Max( Table.Day ) as Day,
                                    Max( Table.Size ) as Size,
                                    Max( Table.[Instance Type] ) as [Instance Type]
                    from Table 
                    where   Table.[Instance Type]="type1" and 
                            Table.[Day]=1 and 
                            1=1 
                    group by Table.[User ID]) as t2 
        on Table.[User ID]<>t2.[User ID]) 
        inner join  (Select top 90  Max( Table.Key ) as Key, 
                                    Max( Table.Instance ) as Instance, 
                                    Table.[User ID], 
                                    Max( Table.Day ) as Day,
                                    Max( Table.Size ) as Size,
                                    Max( Table.[Instance Type] ) as [Instance Type]
                    from Table 
                    where   Table.[Instance Type]="type1" and 
                            Table.[Day]=2 and 
                            1=1 
                    group by Table.[User ID]) as t3 
        on Table.[User ID]<>t3.[User ID]) 

        inner join  (Select Table.[User ID] 
                    from Table 
                    where 1=1 ) as t4 
        on Table.[User ID]=t4.[User ID]) 
where Table.[Instance Type]="type1"
group by Table.[User ID];
```

Any help or advice on how to get what I'm after would be massively appreciated!

Comment: "and I'm not even 100% sure it does exactly what I want." - say, what?

Comment: @MitchWheat: I'm not 100% sure that using the inequality like I do would exclude the items where the User ID doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make things easier for performance tuning to start with chunking this up as temporary tables (in MS-Access, i guess 'views' or 'make-tables', particularly as your logic seems overly complex (and therefore difficult to maintain and debug!):

Part 1 of your question: "Now in my previous question I was building a nested SQL query to find a distinct users who has instance on day 1 and day 2 and in this case with a specific instance type."

Why don't you first use a 'temp table/make table' or 'view' or whatever (depending on how you're implementing, by first getting a distinct list of userid's with the day.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table.UserID, Table.Day
INTO #DistinctListOfUserIDsWithDays /* Not sure of exact syntax in access! */
FROM Table 
WHERE Table.Day = 1 
OR Table.Day = 2
```

And then you can get all users that have data for both days, which solves your first part easily, by aggregating the results of the view/query above and using a having clause:

```
SELECT Table.UserID, COUNT(*)
FROM #DistinctListOfUserIDsWithDays
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
Now I have 2 sets of these queries.
```

re: Your new query, "What I would now like to do is a 3rd query and return the database where the User ID does not exist in either of the other queries", here's one simple solution, based on the original query/view above:

```
SELECT Table.UserID
FROM Table 
WHERE UserID NOT IN (SELECT UserID FROM #DistinctListOfUserIDsWithDays)
```

You cold also outer join #DistinctListOfUserIDsWithDays with the Table and select only those UserID's that return a NULL on the #DistinctListOfUserIDsWithDays side of the query...

Comment: Its a thought I'd had but i was really hoping to be able to create one monolithic SQL select statement (long story but it would be useful for later storage).  Is there a way to create temporary tables as part of the SQL query somehow?

Comment: I'm sure you could take the general logic and convert it - but perhaps easiest would be to just take the original 'temp table' query, convert it to a ms-access 'query' object, and then use the query object in the SQL query - so you'd effectively do the same thing (i.e. use one sql query, without temp tables)

Comment: I've just converted over to trying this (using internal C# objects) and I'm seeing a HUGE increase in performance, which makes me think it IS possible in SQL.  However if noone else comes up with an SQL based answer I will be accepting this answer :)

Comment: So you're using C# with Ms-Access SQL? I assume in that case you're using datasets/readers/etc... If this is the case you could (as mentioned earlier) use *Access Views* (I think called Queries) and then it would be a 'one-pass' SQL query by using the view...  I am sure you could convert your 'virtual table' solution to simpler sql as well (i.e. using the stuff i wrote)